# Unhandled runtime error chakra ui with next js

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I have this run time error in my Next.js app. Seems to have literally came out of no where after weeks of developing problem free.

[image]

seems to trace back to chakra or framer-motion? No idea where I can start here. Has anyone experienced this kind of error? I can provide more info if needed.